# Usage of "which" or "that"

Tags: word-usage

I'm a bit confused with the correct answer in this phrase:

> In Florida, you can explore the Everglades or the beaches, _______
>   are relaxing places.

Is it "*which* are relaxing places" or "*that* are relaxing places"?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a non-restrictive relative clause, so only _which_ is allowed.

Comment: By the way, the above comment could be construed as a more formal way of expressing the below answer, using proper linguistic terms.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock No way :-) The answer below is very wrong indeed! It says that we should use *that* when there isn't a comma! John Lawler's comment says no such thing!

Comment: but leaving out the comma and using "that" makes it a restrictive clause. This does not contradict what Lawler said, but it is rather less elegant. Granted, the choice should not be determined by whether you "want a comma", but rather by what you mean; then the comma use is determined by whether the clause is restrictive or non-restrictive. That's why I upvoted Lawler's comment, but not CactusHouse's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'which,' you're generally saying something without which the sentence would be complete (counter example is this sentence).

In the case you describe, you should say 'which,' because saying beaches are relaxing is an aside following a comma. In cases like those, the rules are clearer. If you want a comma, say 'which;' if you don't want a comma, say 'that.' But choose to say 'which' when what follows is more of a detail than an essential part of the sentence.

Comment: Are you saying that we shouldn't use *which* for defining relative clauses?

Comment: @Araucaria Most likely. In America, that is a common prescriptive rule, though they usually make an exception for 'that which', as in 'That which goes up must come down.'

Comment: @Nothingatall Yes, indeed. There's a few [other times when we have to use *which* and not *that* too](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295879/the-film-that-which-i-selected-for-viewing/299355#299355) :)