# "The one what is blue" - WHAT versus THAT

Tags: grammar, word-usage, relative-clauses, that

I have a student who consistently uses "what" for "that" as in "The one what is blue."  I need to come up with a rule(s) that would work for a 3rd grader, and am having difficulty finding anything.  Lots of pages for "that" vs. "which" and when to use, or not use "that"  But no simple way to help remember this particular piece of grammar.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, this is not dialectical...no one in the family or around this area says it that way.

Comment: "The one what is blue." is just wrong.  There are no circumstances in which you would say it, so you don't need a "rule" to help you remember.

Comment: Sometimes kids need help to remember,  e before i when it isn't after c, is mostly just wrong, but we still got a jaunty line to help drum it into us. I do wish I could come up with something, Seussian seems the way to go, 'said the Thing, what is Blue? yum tee tum detum too...

Comment: https://www.englishforums.com/English/DifferenceBetweenWhat/pwgcg/post.htm

Comment: A basic and insufficient (though it may be sufficient for a third-grader) explanation is: `that` answers `what`. As in "What is that?" So, "What is is blue?" "That is blue." *Typically*, `what` is used to ask a question. If you're making a statement, you *typically* will use `that`.

Comment: @MaxWilliams But why is it wrong?

Comment: Can you put the example in a sentence please? It will make it much easier to answer!

Comment: @Araucaria why is this wrong?  "Cabbages red sunshine foo blink?"

Comment: @MaxWilliams See my answer below. :)

Comment: I've written you a fuller answer. Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The word *which* is used in relative clauses:

- That's the car which I bought yesterday.

Notice that the relative clause  *which I bought yesterday* is giving us more information about the *car* in question. So we have a noun *car*, which is being postmodified by a relative clause. We say that the noun *car* is the *ANTECEDENT* for the relative clause.

The relative pronoun *what* is very different from *which*. We only use the pronoun *what* when there is no antecedent. Look at the following example:

- That is what I bought yesterday.

Here there is no noun before the word *what*. So the word *what* means "the thing which". When we use it we don't name the thing involved. The problem with your student's sentence is that it is using an antecedent, the word *one* with the relative word *what*. In the type of standard English that you are promoting, the word *what* cannot occur with an antecedent.

---

**Mnemonic**

Take any given sentence which this might occur in:

- I like the ball what is blue.

If you ask yourself:

- ***Which*** ball do you like?

... the answer should be:

- The ball **which** is blue.

If they use the right relative pronoun, there is no antecedent 'X' to be able to ask *which X*. This means the sentence was grammatical in the kind of standard English you're aiming at. Consider the sentence:

- I like what I have.

You cannot ask in response to this:

- Which what do you like?

This shows the sentence is fine. You cannot correct it with  *which* and so *what* is correct.

Having said all of this this, this is definitely only something that you would want to correct in writing. There is no point whatsoever trying to correct native speaker's speech. All the evidence shows that this is a complete waste of time and will not work. In addition, you run the risk of damaging you student's self-esteem and making them feel bad, and all for something that is not "fixable".

Although you may not have  heard it before in your local area, this definitely *is* a varietal feature.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are subtle differences between *which* and *that*, which are not explained in this answer. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/which-versus-that-0

Comment: @gfullam Yes, that question is definitely relevant! But Mignon Fogarty is not that hot on that issue, imo. [See here for a different take supported by academic reference grammars](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295879/the-film-that-which-i-selected-for-viewing/299355#299355)

Comment: Apparently I've been following a bogeyman rule, but I'm rethinking that. ;)