# Are the usages of "that" and "which" correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, differences, word-usage, which-that

"I don't like commenting on things about anime series **that** people are currently watching **which** I have seen, and will try to refrain from doing so in the future, but I like how the art style changes over time."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The film \[that/which\] I selected for viewing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295879/the-film-that-which-i-selected-for-viewing)

Comment: They're both fine, and they'd be fine in the opposite order, too. Whether to use _which_ or _that_ is strictly a speaker's choice, depending on how they want it to **sound**. But another tendency is not to stack relative clauses up one after another like this; better to reduce the more restrictive one and put it right after _series_ and leave the other at the end: _series I have seen that people are currently watching_ is easier to read and puts the ideas in order.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> They're both fine, and they'd be fine in the opposite order, too. Whether to use *which* or *that* is strictly a speaker's choice, depending on how they want it to **sound**. But another tendency is not to stack relative clauses up one after another like this; better to reduce the more restrictive one and put it right after *series* and leave the other at the end: *series I have seen that people are currently watching* is easier to read and puts the ideas in order.